# Drawing multiple polygons with vertex buffer object

Tags: opengl, c++, vbo, vertex-buffer

I tried to create program in which I would draw multiplepoygons
here is fragment of what I have done:

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
```

exampleof drawing triangle(I have more polygons, like circle, and so on..)

```
if (figure == RECTANGLE)
{
    data[0][0] = px1;   data[0][1] = py1;
    data[1][0] = px2;   data[1][1] = py1;
    data[2][0] = px2;   data[2][1] = py2;
    data[3][0] = px1;   data[3][1] = py2;
    vertex_count = 4;
}
if (vertex_count > 0)
{
    glGenBuffers(3, VertexArrayID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexArrayID[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * sizeof(float), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//GLfloat* data = (GLfloat*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertex_count);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Now the point is that I want to: 
1) create polygon
2) save this polygon ob buffer
3) create other polygon
4) save that polygon
5) and so..

I know that here I create N buffers:

```
glGenBuffers(N, VertexArrayID);
```

But I need to know how to save each polygon on each buffer, and then show it all on screen.
I tried do use glBufferSubData, glMapBuffer, I have read many tutorials, but still I don't know how to do that.